# How to find out who uploaded data in S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a shared S3 bucket with other members in the team.
Is there a way to find out who uploaded a particular file in the bucket?

Comment: After-the-fact? I don't think so. Going forwards, I believe you can turn on [CloudTrail](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/) for auditing this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

Buckets are owned by an AWS Account, not individual users. When a user makes an API call, AWS authenticates the user and verifies that they have permission to make the call. After that, it is the Account that owns the content. (Although objects can sometimes have a specific owner, which gets even more confusing.)

You can now use AWS CloudTrail to [track data events on Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/11/aws-cloudtrail-supports-s3-data-events/):

> AWS CloudTrail now supports **Amazon S3 Data Events**. You can now record all API actions on S3 Objects and receive detailed information such as the AWS account of the caller, IAM user role of the caller, time of the API call, IP address of the API, and other details.